# How to show sql query with checkboxes with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

i have 3 checkboxes and when i click on it, it should change the sql string and show me a new sql query.

my HTML code:

```
<div id="#check_article">
<input type="checkbox" value="Iphone">Iphone
<input type="checkbox" value="Samsung">Samsung
<input type="checkbox" value="Nokia">Nokia
</div>
```

my script:

```
var arr = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            arr.push(value);
        }
        else {
            arr.splice($.inArray($(this).val(),arr),1);
            }
    var new_string = arr.toString();
    console.log(new_string);
});
```

so when i click on the checkbox my console.log shows me the right value in string. when i uncheck the box it deletes me the value from the string.

now i have to pass it to the server with ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"query.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: {'qry':new_string},
                success:function(data) {
                ('#result').html(data);
                }
        });
```

on php side ... i wolud like to search for a checked article with this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Store WHERE Name LIKE 'mobilePhone' AND Article='....' 
AND Article='....'" AND Article='....';
```

but i realized that i have to format my string.
My string is right now : `"Iphone,Nokia,Samsung"`
but i need it to change to `AND Article= 'Iphone' AND Article = 'Nokia' AND Article='Samsung'`

is this a right way do to it like this or is there a better way ?

Comment: Instead of converting the array to a string in javascript, leave it as an array.  Then, `$_POST[ 'qry' ];` will contain an ARRAY of options, which you can then use to build your query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Convert it to string

In Front end, remove the `toString` method

In PHP File you can do like this

```
 $array = $_POST['qry'];
 $listCheck = "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
 echo $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM Store WHERE Name LIKE IN ($listCheck)";
```